# RightNow CRM XML API - Anyone familiar with it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net, rightnow-crm

I need to create a user control in either vb.net or c# to search a RightNow CRM database. I have the documentation on their XML API, but I'm not sure how to post to their parser and then catch the return data and display it on the page.

Any sample code would be greatly appreciated!

Link to API: http://community.rightnow.com/customer/documentation/integration/82_crm_integration.pdf

Comment: Could you link to their documentation? Others may be able to find the relevant information in it, even if we don't have experience of RightNow ourselves...

Comment: http://community.rightnow.com/customer/documentation/integration/82_crm_integration.pdf

Comment: I don't understand the question really. Are you looking for a sample integration of "right now", or are you asking how to do a HTTP Post with c#?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know RightNow CRM, but according to the documentation you can send the XML requests using HTTP post. The simplest way to do this in .NET is using the WebClient class. Alternatively you might want to take a look at the HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse classes. Here is some sample code using WebClient:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System;

namespace RightNowSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serviceUrl = "http://<your_domain>/cgi-bin/<your_interface>.cfg/php/xml_api/parse.php";
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            string requestXml = 
@"<connector>
<function name=""ans_get"">
<parameter name=""args"" type=""pair"">
<pair name=""id"" type=""integer"">33</pair>
<pair name=""sub_tbl"" type='pair'>
<pair name=""tbl_id"" type=""integer"">164</pair>
</pair>
</parameter>
</function>
</connector>";

            string secString = "";
            string postData = string.Format("xml_doc={0}, sec_string={1}", requestXml, secString);
            byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            byte[] responseDataBytes = webClient.UploadData(serviceUrl, "POST", postDataBytes);
            string responseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseDataBytes);

            Console.WriteLine(responseData);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no access to RightNow CRM, so I could not test this, but it can serve as s tarting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

This will Create a Contact in Right now

```
   class Program
{
    private RightNowSyncPortClient _Service;
    public Program()
    {
        _Service = new RightNowSyncPortClient();
        _Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Rightnow UID";
        _Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Right now password";
    }
    private Contact Contactinfo()
    {
        Contact newContact = new Contact();
        PersonName personName = new PersonName();
        personName.First = "conatctname";
        personName.Last = "conatctlastname";
        newContact.Name = personName;
        Email[] emailArray = new Email[1];
        emailArray[0] = new Email();
        emailArray[0].action = ActionEnum.add;
        emailArray[0].actionSpecified = true;
        emailArray[0].Address = "mail@mail.com";
        NamedID addressType = new NamedID();
        ID addressTypeID = new ID();
        addressTypeID.id = 1;
        addressType.ID = addressTypeID;
        addressType.ID.idSpecified = true;
        emailArray[0].AddressType = addressType;
        emailArray[0].Invalid = false;
        emailArray[0].InvalidSpecified = true;
        newContact.Emails = emailArray;
        return newContact;
    }
    public long CreateContact()
    {
        Contact newContact = Contactinfo();
        //Set the application ID in the client info header
        ClientInfoHeader clientInfoHeader = new ClientInfoHeader();
        clientInfoHeader.AppID = ".NET Getting Started";
        //Set the create processing options, allow external events and rules to execute
        CreateProcessingOptions createProcessingOptions = new CreateProcessingOptions();
        createProcessingOptions.SuppressExternalEvents = false;
        createProcessingOptions.SuppressRules = false;
        RNObject[] createObjects = new RNObject[] { newContact };
        //Invoke the create operation on the RightNow server
        RNObject[] createResults = _Service.Create(clientInfoHeader, createObjects, createProcessingOptions);

        //We only created a single contact, this will be at index 0 of the results
        newContact = createResults[0] as Contact;
        return newContact.ID.id;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program RBSP = new Program();
        try
        {
            long newContactID = RBSP.CreateContact();
            System.Console.WriteLine("New Contact Created with ID: " + newContactID);
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        System.Console.Read();

    }
}
```